# Create a function that returns an array in which each cell contains the address of a string (representing a word)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, malloc

I need some advice concerning this coding exercise:

> Write a function that splits a string into words. Separators will all
>   be non-alphanumeric characters. The function returns an array in which
>   each cell contains the address of a string (representing a word). The
>   last cell must be NULL to terminate the array.

Two things I need help are :
How does my function make a proper return of the array to my main function
and does the malloc array is used properly ?

I think I've missed up the pointer parts because there are errors showing up during compilation.
If you have any idea, please let me know, thanks !

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char **my_str_to_word_array(const char *str)
{
    char* tab_address = NULL;
    int j = 0; /*Nombre de mots*/
    int i = 0;
    char ptr = 0;

    for( i = 0; str[i] != " "; i++)/*Compter le nombre de mots dans la string*/
        if(*str[i] = " ")
            j++;

    tab_address = malloc(sizeof(char) * j); /*tab avec tous les mots compter par j*/
    if (tab_address == NULL)
        exit(0);

    for ( i = 0; str[i] != " "; i++) /*Stocker les adresse dans un tableau */
        if(str[i] = " ")
        {
            i++;
            tab_address[j] = ptr;
        }
        else if (*str[i] = "\0")
            break;

    return ptr;
    free(tab_address);
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[50] = "Hello world";
    my_str_to_word_array(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you want `sizeof(char*)` in malloc since you allocating space for `char` pointers not simple `char`s. `tab_address` should be `char**` and you want to return this not `ptr`. Also any code after the `return ptr;` is dead -> will not execute.

Comment: Please edit the code and fix the indention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work. Note that the code assume `str` is not `NULL`.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h> // added for usage of isalpha function

char **my_str_to_word_array(const char *str)
{
    char** tab_address = NULL; // FIXED: this need to be an array of char* so char**
    int j = 0; /*Nombre de mots*/
    int i = 0;
    //char ptr = 0; // FIXED: This not needed

    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) // FIXED: you want to go until the end of the string
        if(isalpha(str[i])) // FIXED: you want to check for non alphanumeric here not space
            j++;

    tab_address = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (j + 1)); // FIXED: you want to allocate char* -s not char -s
    if (tab_address == NULL)
        exit(0);

    tab_address[0] = str; // ADDED: the first word should be at the start of the string
    j = 1; // FIXED: reinitialize j to 1
    for ( i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) // FIXED: you want to go until the end of the string 
        if(!isalpha(str[i])) // FIXED: you want to check for non alphanumeric here not space
            tab_address[j++] = &str[++i]; // setting the next pointer to the next words address
        //else if (*str[i] = "\0")  // FIXED: these can be deleted
        //    break;

    tab_address[j] = NULL; // ADDED: setting the last element to NULL
    return tab_address; // FIXED: you want to return the char** array not ptr
    // free(tab_address); // FIXED: this is dead code, and you want to free it later anyway
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[50] = "Hello There World";
    char ** result = my_str_to_word_array(str);
    char ** for_freeing = result; // save the start address of the result to later free it

    while (*result != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", *result);
        result++;
    }

    free(for_freeing);

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Hello There World
There World
World
```

Which is actually correct if you think about it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. 
Would be great to print one word per line and to have a line return at each new word.

Comment: You can do this for printing https://onlinegdb.com/ByQoBB-88. If you want to actualy insert new lines into the string that would be more hussle.